# After 40 items inserted into sql data base it all disappears

Tags: php, sql, forms

When i use this script with a form i insert all images until the 40 it works fine when i go past 40 it suddenly disappears when inserted and no record gets added

```
if(isset($_POST['save3']))
{
 if($_POST['pdate1'] !="" && $_POST['pdate2'] !="")
 {
      $pdate=$_POST['pdate1'].' t.e.m '.$_POST['pdate2'];
 }
 else
 {
  $pdate=$_POST['pdate1'];
 }
   $pcircuit=$_POST['pcircuit'];
       $img11desc=base64_encode($_POST['image11description']);
       $img11=base64_encode($_POST['image11']);
       $img11titel=base64_encode($_POST['image11titel']);
       $host="127.0.0.1"; 
       $user="belgiumca_db"; 
       $pw=""; 
       $db="belgiumca_db"; 

       $verbinding=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw) or die("Kan de verbinding niet maken"); 
       mysql_select_db($db);
         $sql = "INSERT INTO images (NameEvent,Date,Bigimage,Bigimagetitel,Bigimagedesc,photodesc,Image1,Image1titel,Image1desc,Image2,Image2titel,Image2desc,Image3,Image3titel,Image3desc,Image4,Image4titel,Image4desc,Image5,Image5titel,Image5desc,Image6,Image6titel,Image6desc,Image7,Image7titel,Image7desc,Image8,Image8titel,Image8desc,Image9,Image9titel,Image9desc,Image10,Image10titel,Image10desc,Image11,Image11titel,Image11desc,Image12,Image12titel,Image12desc,Image13,Image13titel,Image13desc,Image14,Image14titel,Image14desc,Image15,Image15titel,Image15desc,Image16,Image16titel,Image16desc,Image17,Image17titel,Image17desc,Image18,Image18titel,Image18desc,Image19,Image19titel,Image19desc,Image20,Image20titel,Image20desc,Image21,Image21titel,Image21desc,Image22,Image22titel,Image22desc,Image23,Image23titel,Image23desc,Image24,Image24titel,Image24desc,Image25,Image25titel,Image25desc,Image26,Image26titel,Image26desc,Image27,Image27titel,Image27desc,Image28,Image28titel,Image28desc,Image29,Image29titel,Image29desc,Image30,Image30titel,Image30desc,Image31,Image31titel,Image31desc,Image32,Image32titel,Image32desc,Image33,Image33titel,Image33desc,Image34,Image34titel,Image34desc,Image35,Image35titel,Image35desc,Image36,Image36titel,Image36desc,Image37,Image37titel,Image37desc,Image38,Image38titel,Image38desc,Image39,Image39titel,Image39desc,Image40,Image40titel,Image40desc,Image41,Image41titel,Image41desc,Image42,Image42titel,Image42desc,Image43,Image43titel,Image43desc,Image44,Image44titel,Image44desc,Image45,Image45titel,Image45desc,Image46,Image46titel,Image46desc,Image47,Image47titel,Image47desc,Image48,Image48titel,Image48desc,Image49,Image49titel,Image49desc,Image50,Image50titel,Image50desc,Image51,Image51titel,Image51desc,Image52,Image52titel,Image52desc,postedate,postetime,circuit,tags,autor,ip,specimage1,specimage1titel,specimage1desc,specimage2,specimage2titel,specimage2desc,specimage3,specimage3titel,specimage3desc,specimage4,specimage4titel,specimage4desc) VALUES ('".base64_encode($_POST['titelphotos'])."','".base64_encode($pdate)."','".base64_encode($_POST['bigimage'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['bigimagetitel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['bigimagedesc'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['textphotos'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image1'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image1titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image1description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image2'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image2titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image2description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image3'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image3titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image3description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image4'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image4titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image4description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image5'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image5titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image5description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image6'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image6titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image6description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image7'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image7titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image7description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image8'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image8titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image8description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image9'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image9titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image9description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image10'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image10titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image10description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image11'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image11titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image11description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image12'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image12titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image12description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image13'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image13titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image13description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image14'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image14titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image14description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image15'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image15titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image15description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image16'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image16titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image16description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image17'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image17titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image17description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image18'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image18titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image18description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image19'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image19titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image19description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image20'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image20titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image20description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image21'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image21titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image21description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image22'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image22titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image22description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image23'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image23titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image23description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image24'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image24titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image24description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image25'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image25titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image25description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image26'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image26titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image26description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image27'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image27titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image27description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image28'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image28titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image28description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image29'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image29titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image29description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image30'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image30titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image30description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image31'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image31titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image31description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image32'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image32titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image32description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image33'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image33titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image33description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image34'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image34titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image34description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image35'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image35titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image35description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image36'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image36titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image36description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image37'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image37titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image37description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image38'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image38titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image38description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image39'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image39titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image39description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image40'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image40titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image40description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image41'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image41titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image41description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image42'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image42titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image42description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image43'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image43titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image43description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image44'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image44titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image44description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image45'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image45titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image45description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image46'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image46titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image46description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image47'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image47titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image47description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image48'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image48titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image48description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image49'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image49titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image49description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image50'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image50titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image50description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image51'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image51titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image51description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image52'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image52titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['image52description'])."','".base64_encode(date('d-m-Y'))."','".base64_encode(date('H:i:s'))."','".base64_encode($pcircuit)."','".base64_encode($_POST['ptags'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['author'])."','".$ipaddress."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage1'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage1titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage1description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage2'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage2titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage2description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage3'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage3titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage3description'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage4'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage4titel'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['specimage4description'])."')";

 mysql_query($sql); 

 mysql_close($verbinding);
```

// not code !!!
All Columns in table `images`:
// ID= Primary -Auto - increment and integer, all other columns just text

ID,NameEvent,Date,Bigimage,Bigimagetitel,Bigimagedesc,photodesc,Image1,Image1titel,Image1desc,Image2,Image2titel,Image2desc,Image3,Image3titel,Image3desc,Image4,Image4titel,Image4desc,Image5,Image5titel,Image5desc,Image6,Image6titel,Image6desc,Image7,Image7titel,Image7desc,Image8,Image8titel,Image8desc,Image9,Image9titel,Image9desc,Image10,Image10titel,Image10desc,Image11,Image11titel,Image11desc,Image12,Image12titel,Image12desc,Image13,Image13titel,Image13desc,Image14,Image14titel,Image14desc,Image15,Image15titel,Image15desc,Image16,Image16titel,Image16desc,Image17,Image17titel,Image17desc,Image18,Image18titel,Image18desc,Image19,Image19titel,Image19desc,Image20,Image20titel,Image20desc,Image21,Image21titel,Image21desc,Image22,Image22titel,Image22desc,Image23,Image23titel,Image23desc,Image24,Image24titel,Image24desc,Image25,Image25titel,Image25desc,Image26,Image26titel,Image26desc,Image27,Image27titel,Image27desc,Image28,Image28titel,Image28desc,Image29,Image29titel,Image29desc,Image30,Image30titel,Image30desc,Image31,Image31titel,Image31desc,Image32,Image32titel,Image32desc,Image33,Image33titel,Image33desc,Image34,Image34titel,Image34desc,Image35,Image35titel,Image35desc,Image36,Image36titel,Image36desc,Image37,Image37titel,Image37desc,Image38,Image38titel,Image38desc,Image39,Image39titel,Image39desc,Image40,Image40titel,Image40desc,Image41,Image41titel,Image41desc,Image42,Image42titel,Image42desc,Image43,Image43titel,Image43desc,Image44,Image44titel,Image44desc,Image45,Image45titel,Image45desc,Image46,Image46titel,Image46desc,Image47,Image47titel,Image47desc,Image48,Image48titel,Image48desc,Image49,Image49titel,Image49desc,Image50,Image50titel,Image50desc,Image51,Image51titel,Image51desc,Image52,Image52titel,Image52desc,postedate,postetime,circuit,tags,autor,ip,specimage1,specimage1titel,specimage1desc,specimage2,specimage2titel,specimage2desc,specimage3,specimage3titel,specimage3desc,specimage4,specimage4titel,specimage4desc

Comment: What does the table definition look like? I'm guessing it has something to do with this: "Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. Storage engines may place additional constraints on this limit, reducing the effective maximum row size." (from [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html)). If you're using BLOB columns, this does not apply.

Comment: But, I gotta say, forty (or more) columns that are essentially duplicates is not the best way to design your table. I'd try a separate "images" table, each row holding one image, with a one-to-many link to another table.

Comment: Agreed - 180 columns is huge. I'd suggest splitting your image data out into a separate table with a foreign key. That way your number of images can vary, and you don't waste space on records that don't make use of all 50 or so image spaces.

Comment: I'd like to keep it this way because the output for my costumer is already created. i use TEXT columns and i would like to know why the fault keeps showing up @Kryten Could someone see a fault in it ?

Comment: @Alex I know it isn't the best way i use but it looked the most logic one so i did this and i would like to proceed with it. because it took some hours to make this

Comment: I think you're going to need to post your table schema.

Comment: Also, and this is just a random thought, but the original MySQL API (which you're using) is now deprecated as of PHP 5.5. It _could_ be a limitation of PHP (which is never going to be fixed). Try using PDO to access the database.

Comment: I hate to say this but this table layout is not a good idea, if you are in the beginning stages of this project, as in, there is currently no data in this table.  You should seriously reconsider a redesign.  What happens when this table has a ton of rows and you need to add Image53desc?  You are going to have to add an additional column which is an expensive operation on a big table. It will probably take you less time to redesign this into multiple tables then it will to sort out this insert statement.  Also is it absolutly necessary to store the actual image in the db?

Comment: @jacob it's a project that is like 97% finished so i wouldn't like to redesign the user only needs 52 columns/images so i don't see any problem , the images have to be send with it because of the fact it is to display photo's on a webpage

Comment: @Krylen I just updated my Code above with the fields/columns i use maybe something useful ? i declared it a little ...

Comment: You can store the images in a images folder with the rest of your project and have a reference to that folder location (filename) in your table.

Comment: You are storing 50+ images, base64 encoded, in one table? That's a horrible design. Define "it all disappears" Preferably by showing the inevitable error message you're currently ignoring.

Comment: I quess you guys are right about the layout would it be an idea to split up the description+title and the image so a table for the images and one for all the other things ? would this work for me ?

Comment: @AD7six An empty one just works fine and all the images before number 40 work fine once i fill any of the images between 40 and 52 i get no record inserted. Any Idea why ?

Comment: yes that would be a much better idea.  I will still suggest storing your images in files. Then you can have one table with maybe 3 or 4 columns. id, filename, decscipriton

Comment: Because an error occurs you are not checking if the query succeeds - add error checking and _ read the error message_. It's probably something like "data too big"

Comment: @Jacob But how would be able to do that since i am using links for the images(other upload source) saving on diskspace :D , how could i export alway the latest 52 images, with like Putting LIMIT 52 in the Query or something ?

Comment: Using links for images and then pulling that from a database doesn't really make sense to me.  Usually you would have something like http://www.mywebsite.com/images/requestedimage.jpeg where the requested image is stored in the images folder.  In the db you store the file name 'requestedimage.jpeg'.  I am sure I am missing something important that is making you feel that db storage is best.  I am more concerned about your table structure.  That is what you should focus on correcting.

Comment: @Jacob Yeah, But i use an external server for storage so i get my pictures from there it saves me diskspace on buying hosting packs

Comment: But i got an idea on my mind to fix this i will post my solution afterwards with the Insert script and the page where it is shown the output script(Select from query) i will also post here

Answer (score 0):

add

```
echo mysql_error();
```

after

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

and you will see the error